# Integrating R with Python - how to use R magics as input and output of a python process

Tags: python, r, jupyter-notebook

I have a conceptual question for anyone who knows it:  you can use an R magic to run R Plots in Python in a Jupyter cell.  For it to work, after the load statement, you need %%R as the very first line of the cell.  Alternatively, Jupyter has its own plotting including a ggplot, but anecdotally, I am told that the one in R is better maintained and works better.

Is it possible to set things up in Python and then pass them into the R cell and then have the results come back out for Python to work on them again?  Or are R magic cells completely autonomous from other Python cells?

If you export a Jupyter notebook as Python code, and it has the %%R magic in the middle of it, will this work?  Or will it fail because the %%R line is now not at the start of the script?  And if it fails, is there a way to work around that?

The ultimate goal of these questions:  Imagine writing code in Python, using Pandas and other Python libraries to get and manipulate data, then pass the results into R to work its magic for plotting and statistical calculation, then when needed, pass a result from that R magic cell back out for Python to use in some next step.

Is this possible within a Jupyter Notebook?  If so, what do you need to do so your code will work as a .py script as well as a Jupyter Notebook?